# Metafor Package (R) - Adding Multiple Columns

Tags: r, plot

I've currently got a data frame as per below called final

```
final
     Gms AvgPts   max   min   Team salary position playing.status value                         Players
    (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (fctr)  (dbl)   (fctr)         (fctr) (dbl)                           (chr)
1      2  87.00   113    61    STK   4300      FWD          Start 20.23     Tim Membrey, STK, FWD, 4300
2      4  75.50   124    42    STK   4300      MID          Start 17.56     Blake Acres, STK, MID, 4300
3      7  77.43   119    50    STK   5500       RU          Start 14.08       Tom Hickey, STK, RU, 5500
4      6  87.00   110    54    WCE   6200       RU    Interchange 14.03     Scott Lycett, WCE, RU, 6200
5      5  71.40    89    39    STK   5200      FWD    Interchange 13.73   Jack Sinclair, STK, FWD, 5200
6      3  73.33    83    68    WCE   5400      MID          Start 13.58  Mark Hutchings, WCE, MID, 5400
7      7  98.71   127    83    STK   7400      MID    Interchange 13.34  Sebastian Ross, STK, MID, 7400
8      7  79.14    99    53    WCE   6100      DEF          Start 12.97 Jeremy McGovern, WCE, DEF, 6100
9      7 108.29   198    67    WCE   8500      FWD          Start 12.74 Josh J. Kennedy, WCE, FWD, 8500
10     6 121.00   150    57    STK   9500      FWD          Start 12.74   Nick Riewoldt, STK, FWD, 9500
11     6  79.17   101    59    STK   6400      MID          Start 12.37    Luke Dunstan, STK, MID, 6400
12     7  84.86   104    60    STK   7000      DEF          Start 12.12    Shane Savage, STK, DEF, 7000
13     7  82.14   100    45    WCE   6900      FWD          Start 11.90    Jack Darling, WCE, FWD, 6900
14     7  95.29   138    76    WCE   8100       RU          Start 11.76     Nic Naitanui, WCE, RU, 8100
15     7  87.43   135    53    WCE   7500      FWD          Start 11.66     Mark LeCras, WCE, FWD, 7500
16     7  74.29    92    34    WCE   6400      DEF          Start 11.61   Brad Sheppard, WCE, DEF, 6400
```

I use the following lines of code to produce a forest plot as shown below:

```
forest(x = final$AvgPts, ci.lb = final$min, ci.ub = final$max, slab = final$Players,ilab = final$value, ilab.xpos = max(final$max)+10,ilab.pos =4,yaxs="i", alim = c(min(final$min)-5, max(final$max)+5),steps = 4, xlim = c(min(final$min)-200, 2*(max(final$max)+5)), xlab = "Moneyball Points Spread", efac = 0.75-.0014*k, cex = 0.75, mgp = c(1, 1, 0),refline=mean(final$AvgPts),digits=1,col="dark blue",pch = 19,main=paste("2016 Moneyball Summary - pos =",paste(as.character(pos), collapse=", "),"\n(avg >=",points,"-- value >=",val,"-- TOG >=",time,")"))

text(min(final$min)-200, (nrow(final) + 1.5), "Player",pos=4,cex=0.75)
text(max(final$max)+10, (nrow(final) + 1.5), "Value",pos=4,cex=0.75)
text(2*(max(final$max)+5), (nrow(final) + 1.5), "Average[min,max]",pos=2,cex=0.75)
```

[image]

What I want to be able to do is add more columns than just the Value column (ilab = final$value).

Ideally I would like a solution which would be able to fit more than just one additional column as I intend to build on the final data frame with more information.

Also, is it possible to add extra columns before AND after the plot line section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ilab` argument can also take an entire matrix or data frame (and `ilab.pos` and `ilab.xpos` should then be vectors). See `help(forest.rma)` for examples. And yes, if you adjust `xlim` so there is sufficient space to the left and the right of the points and CI lines, you can place the information to the left and right as well (just use `ilab.xpos` to specify where you want the various columns placed).